# KeyError altering columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, keyerror

I'm trying to change column or deal with columns and I'm getting some keyError error. Working on chicago crime data analysis.

For example when i'm trying to run

```
ds["DATE OF OCCURRENCE"] = pd.to_datetime([ds["DATE OF OCCURRENCE"]], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

KeyError

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
```

Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
url="https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/x2n5-8w5q/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"
df= pd.read_csv(url)
ds = df.copy()
ds["DATE OF OCCURRENCE"] = pd.to_datetime([ds["DATE OF OCCURRENCE"]], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

This is the Error:

> 2896             try:
> -> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2898             except KeyError:
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'DATE OF OCCURRENCE'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) 2 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2897                 return
> self._engine.get_loc(key)    2898             except KeyError:
> -> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))    2900
> indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
> 2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'DATE OF OCCURRENCE'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column is renamed, so need `Crime_Date` and also select column only one `[]`  for `Series`:

```
ds["Crime_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(ds["Crime_Date"], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

EDIT:

There are some spaces in column name, so need:

```
ds["DATE  OF OCCURRENCE"] = pd.to_datetime(ds["DATE  OF OCCURRENCE"], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

Comment: I removed all the renaming and cleared the runtme and now after running this code:
import pandas as pd
url="https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/x2n5-8w5q/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"
df= pd.read_csv(url, encoding = "utf-8")
df["DATE OF OCCURRENCE"] = pd.to_datetime([df["DATE OF OCCURRENCE"]], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

I'm still getting it.